# Xsl with export to excel not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

i got stuck with a small task. my task is export dataset values to excel with using Xsl technique. Assume there is four data tables in a dataset (Table,Table1,Table2 and Table3 respectively). Note when i run this code im my local machine its working fine. but not in Server machine. I got following message
"Unable to load the web page because the server sent no data.
Reload this web page.
Press the reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.
Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

## My Code:

```
void GenerateLeaveReport(string type)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    IAttendanceHandler antHandler = new AttendanceHandler(_masterPage.Controller);
    XmlDocument report = new XmlDocument();

    //int department = Convert.ToInt32(ddlDepartment.SelectedValue.ToString());
    int month = Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonth.SelectedValue.ToString());
    int year = Convert.ToInt32(txtYear.Text.ToString());
    string month_name = ddlMonth.SelectedItem.ToString();

    try
    {
        ds = antHandler.GetAttendaceLeaveReport(month, year);

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.Charset = "";
            XmlDataDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDataDocument(ds);
            XslCompiledTransform xslTran = new XslCompiledTransform();
            xslTran.Load(Server.MapPath("../xsl/LeaveReport.xsl"));
            // xslTran.Load(Server.MapPath("../xsl/LeaveReport1.xsl"));

            // Program flow does not cross this line, is there any error in 
            // Response.OutputStream.
            xslTran.Transform(xmlDoc, null, Response.OutputStream);
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
            string fn = "LeaveReport" + "-" + month_name+"-"+year.ToString();
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fn + ".xls");
            Response.End();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // Error message
    }
}
```

Regards Sarva

Comment: Make sure you've specified file at Server.MapPath("../xsl/LeaveReport.xsl") location

Comment: as i have mentioned above code block there is no issues in code but its not cross "xslTran.Transform(xmlDoc, null, Response.OutputStream);" this line  @malkam. thats why i confused

Comment: yes it's there... im sure